# How to check if one factor affects Y variable when we have two factors?

Tags: anova, multiple-regression

I am unsure of what is considered a typical approach to a situation where we have 2 factors (let's say they each have 3 levels) and we just want to specifically see if one of the factors has an effect on our Y value.

I had been playing with hypothetical data using R and couldn't decide what to do. So imagine I want to see if factor 1 affects the Y value.

Initially I made a linear model just using factor 1 and the Y variable
-  my_lm<- lm(Y ~ factor1, data = blah). I then ran this through an anova to get its F value.
- anova(my_lm)

but then I thought maybe I would be better using both factors in the model.
 - my_lm2<- lm(Y ~ factor1 + factor2 , data = blah)
get its F value.
- anova(my_lm2)

Is one approach more right than the other?

Comment: I would say, you need to specify your problem in more details. Do you want to marginalize the other factors or account for them? Consider the following example: Y=salary, factor1=gender, factor2=whether you work in government or private sector, possibleFactor3=occupation. Does factor1 have an effect on Y?

Comment: Using your example, my goal would be to determine whether or not salary is effected by gender (in isolation, i.e ignoring the other factors), but what I am unsure of then is what instance woudl I wnat to accoutn for the other factors ?

Comment: Thr question is confusing .